# How to evaluate the following sum if $n$ is an even number?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, special-functions, integers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

In a mathematical physical problem, the sum below needs to be calculated:

$$
F_n(\xi) =
 \sum_{k=0}^{\operatorname{ceil} \left(\frac{n}{2}-1 \right)} (-1)^k \frac{\xi^{2k}}{n-2k}
=
 \begin{cases}
  \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad ? & \text{if $n$ is even} \, , \\
  (-1)^{\frac{n-1}{2}} \xi^{n-1} \Big( 1+\frac{1}{2} \Phi \left( -\xi^2,1,-\frac{1}{2} \right) \Big) - \frac{1}{2} \Phi \left( -\xi^2, 1, -\frac{n}{2} \right) & \text{if $n$ is odd} \, , 
 \end{cases}
$$
wherein $\xi$ is a positive real number.
Here, $\operatorname{ceil}(x)$ denotes the ceiling function, which maps a variable $x$ to the least integer greater than or equal to $x$.
Accordingly,
$$
\operatorname{ceil}\left( \frac{n}{2}-1 \right)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{n}{2}-1 & \text{if $n$ is even} \, , \\
\frac{n-1}{2} & \text{if $n$ is odd} \, .
\end{cases}
$$

When $n$ is an odd number, it turned out that the sum can conveniently be expressed in terms of the Lerch transcendent function.
However, when $n$ is even, i have no idea how to evaluate the sum.

It would be highly appreciated if someone here could try to be of help and let me know whether an analytical evaluation is possible. Any hint would be most welcome!

Comment: @Maxim you helped last time in a similar problem. Do you have any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n=2m$, Maple says the sum is
$$
-{\frac { \left( -{\xi}^{2} \right) ^{m}}{2\;m} \left( \ln  \left( {
\frac {{\xi}^{2}+1}{{\xi}^{2}}} \right) m+ \left( {\xi}^{2} \right) ^{
-m} \left( -1 \right) ^{m} \left( {\it LerchPhi} \left( -{\xi}^{-2},1,
m \right) m-1 \right)  \right) }
$$

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Trying $n=2$ for example in Maple leads to the error Error, (in LerchPhi) numeric exception: division by zero -- Any ideas how to get rid of that?

Comment: This works -- thanks! i was using an older version of Maple (15) and it does not know that.